# Unity IOS - UI slider automatic reset zero

Tags: unity-game-engine, slider

I updated the value of `slider` like this:

```js
void Update()
{
    slider.value = ....
}
```

When I build and test:

- Android: slider value worked.
- IOS: slider value worked but automatic reset 0.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If so please post these aswel.

Comment: @remy_rm Thank you for your comment. This issue is resolved :)